# php mysql - insert one query from a while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a loop and submit form. I want to insert one query from a variable but when I click on the submit button last one (id number) variable inserts to the database and when I move `$_POST['submit']` part inside the while all ID's insert to the database. How can I insert one of the variables from loop?

This is the while part:

```
<?php
    $supql="SELECT * FROM `tbl_users_posts`";
    $rez=mysqli_query($conn,$supql);
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rez)) {
        $psid=$row['id'];
        echo $row['post'];
?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>                             
<?php } ?>
```

And this is the submit part:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $pid=$_POST['postid'];
    $inslik="INSERT INTO t_plik (pid,uid)VALUES('$psid','$uid')";
    mysqli_query($conn,$inslik);
}
```

thanks

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','sitn');mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
$supql="SELECT * FROM `tbl_users_posts`";
$rez=mysqli_query($conn,$supql);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rez)){
    $psid=$row['id'];
    echo $row['post'];
    ?>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="postid" value="<?php echo $psid; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>                 
    <?php }?>
<?php                                       
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $pid=$_POST['postid'];
    $inslik="INSERT INTO t_plik (pid,uid)VALUES('$psid','$uid') ";
    mysqli_query($conn,$inslik);
}?>
```

Comment: Not your answer, but very important: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). Please fix it by using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form has no input with `name="postid"`, so `$_POST['postid']` wasn't being set. You can send this with a hidden input.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="postid" value="<?php echo $psid; ?>">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The form should still be in the `while` loop, so you'll get a separate form for each post.

You also have a typo in the code that does the inserting:

```
$pid=$_POST['postid'];
```

should be:

```
$psid=$_POST['postid'];
```

So you weren't inserting the ID that was submitted.

Comment: doesnt change any thing!

Comment: It should fix it. Your form has no `name="postid"`, so nothing gets put into `$_POST['postid']`. This fixes that.

Comment: when i click on the submit button, inserts 20-30 query with  12-13-14-15... numbers

Comment: I don't see any way that could happen from one submit, unless you have the `INSERT` in a loop.

Comment: I think you need to post more of the script, there's more going on than what you posted.

Comment: i added all in the end of first post

Comment: @behzad Maybe should add: $psid = (isset($psid))?$psid:"";

Comment: @behzad Have you try this alse: `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`

Comment: @behzad What is `$uid`

Comment: @MalusJan undefined,it's not important!

Comment: I still don't see any way that can do more than one insert each time you click submit. What do you see if you add `echo "Inserting $psid<br>";` before the `INSERT` query?

Comment: echo "Inserting $psid<br>"; show one by one number "Inserting 1-2-3..." but submit button insert last one number

Comment: Are you saying that it's displaying the "Inserting" message even when you didn't click the Submit button?

Comment: yes! i do put echo "Inserting $psid<br>"; after the echo $row['post']; .

Comment: I just added to my answer. You were setting the wrong variable in before the insert.

Comment: i change $pid to $psid and it works! i cant bleave that. thanks